# DirectX 11 Loading multiple textures into Texture2DArray

Tags: c++, arrays, com, loading, directx-11

Is there a way of taking an array of ID3D11Texture2D* objects and putting them together in a single ID3D11Texture2D* (with an appropriate ArraySize value) that will allow me to use a Texture2DArray in HLSL with them?

At the very least, how do you pass in the individual textures when creating a new ID3D11Texture2D object after you have set ArraySize to greater than 1? Do you need to pass in an array of SUBRESOURCE_DATA structs with each pointing to a texture to the CreateTexture2D function? I've been looking around for an answer to this, but the documentation seems severely lacking.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy existing textures to a texture array, you can use [CopySubresourceRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-copysubresourceregion) using the destination subresource index described below.

To create a new texture array with initial data, you specify multiple subresources (array slices / mip levels) using an array of SUBRESOURCE_DATA structures.  Subresource index is defined as `mip slice + array slice * mip leves`. So for a 2-slice 3-MIP texture array, you would have the following subresources:

```
[0]: slice 0 mip 0
[1]: slice 0 mip 1
[2]: slice 0 mip 2
[3]: slice 1 mip 0
[4]: slice 1 mip 1
[5]: slice 1 mip 2
```

This is described in more detail at the following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-subresources

Comment: That looks like just what I'm looking for! But just to be clear, do you need to copy each individual mip level from a texture into the array texture, one at a time (making sure to add 1 to each destination index)

Comment: If you're going with the CopySubresourceRegion approach, then yes, you need to copy one subresource at a time. But in that case you should consider just using the array resource to begin with so you can avoid a copy.